# Trigger CSS Animation on div click

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get a series of **li** to animate when a div is clicked.
I have tried a few different things but I am not able to get it to work.
For example I have looked at toggling .animate based on a MDN article but this didn't work.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationstart_event

On StackOverflow another user had this problem and a user suggested using controlAnimation()

The result must be repeatable every time the div is clicked.

```js
document.getElementById("clickable").addEventListener("click", controlAnimation);


function controlAnimation() {
   document.getElementById('menu-main-menu').style.animation="fadeInMenu";
   
}
```

```css
#menu-main-menu li {
    
  border-bottom: solid 1px #999;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: fadeInMenu 0.5s 1;
  animation: fadeInMenu 0.5s 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#menu-main-menu li:nth-child(5n+1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

#menu-main-menu li:nth-child(5n+2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

#menu-main-menu li:nth-child(5n+3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

#menu-main-menu li:nth-child(5n+4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
  animation-delay: 0.7s;
}

#menu-main-menu li:nth-child(5n+5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.9s;
  animation-delay: 0.9s;
}



/* Animation steps */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInMenu {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.0;
    transform: translateY(16px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInMenu {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.0;
    transform: translateY(16px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
```

```html
<div id="clickable" >Click me</div>
<br>
<ul id="menu-main-menu">
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
<li>Item 5</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Your event listener isn't correct, `.addEventListener("click", controlAnimation())` should be `.addEventListener("click", controlAnimation)`

Comment: I updated the event listener but it still didn't work. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that in your code, the elements that have "animation" css rules are the LI elements.  So changing the animation property of the UL's style won't work.

Here I changed your CSS a bit so that you can give the UL the class of "animate" and the child LIs will animate.  When you press the button it removes that class, and then using a setTimeout re-adds it, it should reset and replay the animation.

```js
document.getElementById("clickable").addEventListener("click", controlAnimation);


function controlAnimation() {
  const menu = document.querySelector('#menu-main-menu');
  menu.classList.remove('animate');
  setTimeout(() => {
    menu.classList.add('animate');
  }, 0);
}
```

```css
#menu-main-menu li {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #999;
}

#menu-main-menu.animate li {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: fadeInMenu 0.5s 1;
  animation: fadeInMenu 0.5s 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#menu-main-menu.animate li:nth-child(5n+1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

#menu-main-menu.animate li:nth-child(5n+2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

#menu-main-menu.animate li:nth-child(5n+3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

#menu-main-menu.animate li:nth-child(5n+4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
  animation-delay: 0.7s;
}

#menu-main-menu.animate li:nth-child(5n+5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.9s;
  animation-delay: 0.9s;
}



/* Animation steps */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInMenu {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.0;
    transform: translateY(16px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInMenu {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.0;
    transform: translateY(16px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
```

```html
<div id="clickable" >Click me</div>
<br>
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class='animate'>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
<li>Item 5</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That `setTimeout` helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

try adding a animation time to your `document.getElementById('menu-main-menu').style.animation="fadeInMenu";` so like: `document.getElementById('menu-main-menu').style.animation="fadeInMenu 2s";`
(change the 2s to your animation time)